# Why does naming a dataclass field `date` cause RecursionError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

```py
from datetime import date
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  date: date = dataclasses.field()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py", line 1002, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash, frozen)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py", line 979, in _process_class
    str(inspect.signature(cls)).replace(' -> None', ''))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 3040, in __str__
    formatted = str(param)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 2558, in __str__
    formatannotation(self._annotation))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 1199, in formatannotation
    return repr(annotation)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py", line 249, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py", line 249, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/dataclasses.py", line 249, in __repr__
    return ('Field('
  [Previous line repeated 491 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But this works:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  date: date
```

So does this:

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  date_: date = dataclasses.field()
```

Is that a bug, or by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
date: date = dataclasses.field()
```

doesn't annotate `date` as `datetime.date`. It annotates `date` as `dataclasses.field()`, because the annotation is evaluated after the assignment. `dataclasses` doesn't expect a field to have itself as its annotation, and you didn't want that either.

Use something like

```
import datetime
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class A:
  date: datetime.date = dataclasses.field()
```